# Query table opens Excel file when it's not done yet (VB.NET)

Tags: excel, vb.net, text-files

I am working on an application that reads a large tab delimited text file and returns an excel file with multiple sheets with the same data.

I have been able to create the file successfully. However, I have come across a problem. When I import the file into a newly-created excel file the file opens when the first file is imported. I don't want that to happen, I want it to be opened by the user when all the files have been successfully imported.

The interesting thing is that this didn't happen when I was debugging the application at first. So I am baffled as to why it's happening now. Could it be because I am missing a member for the Query table?

Can you please help me? Thanks!

EDIT: I found out that adding headers to the file was the cause of this problem. However, after editing them to the point they're no longer understandable I still can't get it to work.

headers:

```
encabezados = {"Name",
        "Description",
        "listingId", "SKU", "price", "quantity", "Date", "image", "item",
        "productId", "Shipping", "note", "condition", "category1", "browsepath", "storefrontfeature",
        "asin", "asins", "asinss", "willshipinternationally", "expeditedshipping", "zshopboldface", "producid", "bidForfeaturedplacement", "adddelete",
        "pendingquantity", "fulfillmentchannel", "BusinessPrice", "QuantityPriceType", "QuantityLowerBound", "QuantityPrice", "QuantityLowerBounds",
        "QuantityPrices", "QuantityLowerBoundss", "QuantityPricess", "QuantityLowerBoundsss", "QuantityPricesss", "QuantityLowerBoundssss",
        "QuantityPricessss", "merchantshippinggroup"}
```

Function:

```
Private Sub createExcel(pagina)
    Dim hoja = 1
    Dim excel As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    If excel Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error. Excel 2016 no está instalado en esta computadora", "Error")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim iSheetsPerBook As Integer
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    excel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = pagina

    For i = 1 To pagina
        iSheetsPerBook = excel.SheetsInNewWorkbook
        xlWorkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        excel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = iSheetsPerBook
    Next

    For x = 1 To pagina
        Dim archivo = String.Format("{0}\ArchivosExcel\excel{1}.txt", dondeEstaElArchivo, x)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(hoja)
        Dim qt As QueryTable = xlWorkSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=String.Format("TEXT;{0}", archivo), Destination:=xlWorkSheet.Range("$A$1"))

        With qt
            .Name = "Import"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 1252
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = GetColumnDataTypes(xlWorkSheet.Columns.Count)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh(BackgroundQuery:=False)
        End With

        hoja += 1
    Next


    Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveDialog.Title = "Por favor elija donde quiere guardar el archivo"
    saveDialog.Filter = "Excel 2007-on (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    Dim respuesta = saveDialog.ShowDialog()
    If respuesta = DialogResult.Cancel Or saveDialog.FileName = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim fileSave = saveDialog.FileName
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileSave)
    xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    excel.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(excel)
End Sub


Private Function GetColumnDataTypes(queryTableColumnsCount As Long) As Object
    Dim textDataTypes As XlColumnDataType()
    textDataTypes = Enumerable.Repeat(XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat, queryTableColumnsCount).ToArray()
    Return textDataTypes
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason:

The problem was caused by the headers being inserted *before* the text file import. I ended up inserting them after the import and it worked like a charm.